# Set an environment variable when a Visual Studio 2010 Unit Test project runs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, environment-variables

I'd like to modify PATH (to include the path to an alternate Oracle client than the one my workstation usually uses) before unit tests run (or debug). How can this be done? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I'm getting on by starting VS2010 via a BAT file that sets PATH before doing 'start devenv.exe'